# how to delete padding around image view programmatically in android

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

I have 4 imageview in one rows but i wanted to visible and gone need to do based on response. so how to remove unused space which i hardcoded layout.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFacebookUrl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook_login_guest"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLinkdinUrl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_linkdin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void setPadding (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

> Sets the padding. The view may add on the space required to display
>   the scrollbars, depending on the style and visibility of the
>   scrollbars. So the values returned from getPaddingLeft(),
>   getPaddingTop(), getPaddingRight() and getPaddingBottom() may be
>   different from the values set in this call.

**`Finally`**

```
ImageView ImageViewObj = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLinkdinUrl);
ImageViewObj.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

This deletes all paddings (all sides) for your `imgLinkdinUrl` `ImageView`:

```
ImageView linkedInUrlImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLinkdinUrl);
linkedInUrlImage.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```